# cURL - How to sucessfull cal with an internal wsdl (scripting)

Tags: curl, soap, wsdl, soapui

i ther, i am trying to stabelche a call via cURL, but this endpoint is different, i cant connect by browser, even i cant see the structure of WSDL.

If i try using it by a browser, i receive this answer:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

and i get the same response via cURL

[image: cURL activity V 7.69]

[image]

I can make an request by SoapUi successfully because i did need to download the WSDL and the files XSD from intranet of the company and located on my desktop like this:
[image]
[image]

there is a way to complete a request and receive the response via cURL without the WSDL online?

Answer (score 0):

I did it, some stupid thing :D it was because of may request xml, it should have @ instead of the path, from where i em using my cURL, it should be at the same path of my request.